# Android Facebook Integration Invalid Key hash error on Android device but working fine on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-facebook, android-debug

When I run my Android app in my android device it was working fine when I clicked first time on **Continues with Facebook** button.When i try to login again after logged out it is showing an error "Invalid Key has" The key has does not match any stored key hash. I have already  regenerated key hash and replaced new key on facebook. bUt still did not get result.

[First time I had easily logged-in, But after logged out again I'm trying to **Continues with Facebook** but it is showing an error message "Invalid Key has":](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Nn3.png)

But the same application is running perfectly fine on Emulator. why it is not working on my devices?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Put this code in any reachable activity's onCreate method to print the hash key in the console and update that hash key in your facebook linked account with the application.

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

Comment: replace "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto"  with your package name and update in that key in facebook developer console-> your app settings

Comment: Ohh yeah i got it.. Actually I copied wrong haskKey from console, Last letter was missing i.e '='  now it's working perfectly fine.... Thankyou so much.

Comment: :-) It happens with almost every developer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do -

Download openSSl from [Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads) Extract it. create a folder- OpenSSL in C:/ and copy the extracted code here.

detect debug.keystore file path. If u didn't find, then do a search in C:/ and use the Path in the command in next step.

detect your keytool.exe path and go to that dir/ in command prompt and run this command in 1 line-

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

it will ask for password, put android that's all. u will get a key-hash