# Key hashes invalid for facebook and linkedin android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, linkedin-api

When I generate a signed apk, my facebook and linkedin key hashes are invalid, but if I run directly from my machines it's working. How can I resolve this?

I also added key hashes that were required, but did not get any solution.

I already refered to the following links :

[Release apk Facebook hash key not same with generated one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512330/release-apk-facebook-hash-key-not-same-with-generated-one)

[android facebook integration invalid key hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash)

Everything works fine when I run apk with usb directly, but I have problems with generating a signed apk.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Put this code in any reachable activity's onCreate method to print the hash key in the console and update that hash key in your facebook linked account with the application, replace "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto" with your package name and update in that key in facebook developer console-> your app settings and copy paste the keys including "="

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

For reference check my answer on this post. [Android Facebook Integration Invalid Key hash error on Android device but working fine on Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345521/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash-error-on-android-device-but-workin/47346139#47346139)

Comment: Can you please explain in detail , where u r facing problem.

Comment: when i generate signed apk and install in my device keyhash is invalid

Comment: try adding the generated key in to your facebook developer console aur verify it once again because this proble only arises when you key hash is not correct which is added in to facebook developer console.

Comment: i already add the keyhash in developer facebook account  but still problem not resolved.

Comment: can you paste that key here?

Comment: yes i change the key but still i get the same error.